# How to make a bootstrap modal that displays an error when the email is already in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for the best practice used to check the email address of a user on a bootstrap modal element.
 I want to display an error message after he has submit the form and if its email is already present in the database.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

```
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="false" href="#formular" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn" style="margin-right: 3px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Log Up</button>



      <div class="modal fade" id="formular">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">

              <form method="post" action="">

                <div class="form-group mail">

                  <label for="mail">Mail address</label>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Votre email">

                </div>

                <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger" style="display:none">
                  <h4>Error !</h4>
                  Email already exist !
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>

              </form>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>




<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script>


    $(function(){

      $("form").on("submit", function() {

          // if EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS    

              $("#formular").modal({"backdrop": "static"});

              $("div.alert").show("slow").delay(9999).hide("slow");

          return false;

        });

      });



</script>
```

**Here is a Php function that would return true if email exists:**

```
  <?php

    function mail_exist(){

        try
          {
              $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web_site;charset=utf8', 'root', '',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));
          }
          catch(Exception $e)

          {
              die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
          }


          $mails = $bdd -> prepare("SELECT email FROM users") or die(errorInfo());
          $mails->execute();

          while ($donnees = $mails->fetch())
          {

            if ($donnees['email']==$_POST['mail']){
              return true;
            }
          }

          return false;
    }

  ?>
```

As you can see, some code is missing in the Javascript/JQuery part, I guess there are several solutions but I need the most common one, the one that works for sure.

Thanks a lot.

Henry

Comment: Have you tried using ajax?

Comment: add an ajax call to php, pass email, if response if false stop submitting, show error?

Comment: Hello do you want to use ajax or page load submit

Comment: Thank you all, but is it possible to show how you would implement it (i.e show piece of code)?I did not find any code on this particular issue and I think it would be useful for a lot of people.

Comment: @smartnet I don't know ajax actually, what I want is to "stay" on the modal element and show the error on it when email already exists, if not I want to redirect the user to another page

Comment: `mysql_error()` doesn't work with PDO, btw. If your query fails, you won't know what it is. Edit: to which you just edited now `errorInfo()` after I said this, as per http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42901627/1

Comment: and how are you calling this `mail_exist()` function?

Comment: @Fred he never does

Comment: Where are u using the function?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile They never responded to my comment, so this question is both unclear and too broad. The latter meaning: *"Can you write it for me?"* - Not going to happen.

Comment: @LeszekRepie Ok I have read about AJAX, so I must send an `XMLHttpRequest()` request to the server (on a check.php file that check if mail is present), but do I pass the `$_POST['mail']` to the `XMLHttpRequest()` and how, or do I redirect the form action attribute to the check.php ?

Comment: @Henri u might need to respond to other's as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ajax for this task, and also you don't need to put your form inside a modal. and also in your code above you are not showing where are u calling your php function.

This how your code should look :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formular">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger">
                    <h4>Error !</h4>
                    Email already exist !
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form method="post" action="" id="myform">
    <div class="form-group mail">
        <label for="mail">Mail address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Votre email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){

     $('form').on('submit',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var formData = $('form').serialize();

       $.ajax({

         type : 'post',
         data : formData,
          url : 'functions.php',
          dataType : 'json',
          encode : true,
          success : function(response){

          //  response = JSON.parse(response);
             if(response == "exists"){

                $('#formular').modal('toggle');
             }else{

               alert('email does not exist');
                setTimeout(' window.location.href = "anotherPage.php"; ', 6000);//redirecting to another page

             }
         },
             error : function(data){

                console.log(data); // debugging puporses only
             }

       });
     });

    });
</script>
```

then your **functions.php**

```
 <?php

function mail_exist()
{
    $message = '';
    // get the email from ajax
    $email   = $_POST['mail'];

    // don't forget to validate the email both front and server side
    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web_site;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT
        ));
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }


    $mails = $bdd->prepare("SELECT email FROM users where email = ? ");
    $mails->execute([$email]);

    $results = $mails->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (count($results) > 0) {
        //email exists
        $message = 'exists';
    } else {

        $message = 'does not exists';
    }

    echo json_encode($message);

}

mail_exist();

?>
```